# UpdatePanel hides a dynamic div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following UpdatePanel linked to a timer in a trigger.
As you can see I have two components in the content template.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrNotifications" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNotifications"></asp:Label>
        <div id="notificationsDiv" runat="server"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a notification center which is a div that slides down and up on click.

My problem is that when the notification center is open and the timer resets, the notification center disappears.

What can I do to keep it as it is if it was open but update what is inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to put the div around the update panel then have the update panel only update the content inside.

What you're doing there will re-draw the label and div every time the update occurs.